# Unicode string in python

Tags: python

I have

```
(Pdb) email
'\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00@\x00g\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m\x00'
(Pdb) print email
test@gmail.com
```

I need to validate whether thie value is an email format, however, how can i convert this string to actual ascii string?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's encoded with utf-16 encoding.

```
>>> '\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00@\x00g\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m\x00'.decode('utf-16')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 28: truncated data
```

and truncated:

```
>>> '\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00@\x00g\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m\x00'[1:].decode('utf-16')
u'test@gmail.com'

>>> '\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00@\x00g\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m\x00'[1:].decode('utf-16-le')
u'test@gmail.com'
>>> '\x00t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00@\x00g\x00m\x00a\x00i\x00l\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m\x00'.decode('utf-16-be', 'ignore')
u'test@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Truncated in one or the other direction; little endian or big endian.

Comment: If I had to guess about the truncation, I'd blame something splitting on whitespace. The UTF-16 encoding of the space character will be `'\x00 '` or `' \x00'` depending on byte order, which a straight `split` will mangle. Or any other ascii whitespace, of course. You can't safely split an encoded bytestring, especially not UTF-16. `strip` has similar potential to mangle things.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your email to an ASCII string can be done like this :

```
str(email.decode('utf-16le'))
```